# Верна ли поправленная мной авторская пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

> Если наскучили пицца, паста и бычьи желудки, и даже хвосты или вдруг
>   кто-то томится по далёкой Индии, в любом случае приятное разнообразие
>   в рацион внесёт симпатичный ресторан домашней индийской кухни.

Так у автора. Возможно, произошло наслоение авторской, редакторской и корректорской правок при первой читке.

Как спасти ситуацию?

*Если наскучили пицца, паста, и бычьи желудки, и даже хвосты, или вдруг кто-то томится по далёкой Индии, - в любом случае приятное разнообразие в рацион внесёт симпатичный ресторан домашней индийской кухни.*

Это я сейчас нарисовала. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Аргументированно.

---

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, запятая перед *или* не нужна. Kонструкция такая:

*Если наскучили пицца или кто-то томится, то...*

Но слова *в любом случае* требуют чтобы случаи был перечислены, а этого нет.
Предлагаю такие варианты:

Наскучили пицца....; кто-то томится — в любом случае...
Если наскучили пицца...., если вдруг кто-то томится — в любом случае...
Тире вместо запятой в СПП.

**Если наскучили пицца, паста, и бычьи желудки, и даже хвосты, если вдруг кто-то томится по далёкой Индии — в любом случае приятное разнообразие в рацион внесёт симпатичный ресторан домашней индийской кухни.**

Comment: Думаю, если хвосты всё же бычьи, то лучше хотя бы так: **Если наскучили пицца, паста, бычьи желудки и даже хвосты**. А то принадлежность этих хвостов не совсем понятна, особенно если всё разбито запятыми. А в остальном согласна с Вами.

Comment: @Наталья Я подумал, что хвосты вообще, а если только бычьи (скорее всего, именно так), то Вы правы.

Comment: Что-то с хвостами неладно. Надо бы явно сказать: бычьи желудки и даже бычьи хвосты. Или так: даже бычьи желудки и хвосты.

Comment: Да, согласна с Вами.

Comment: Спасибо! Но не получается с *если... или кто-то томится*, "или" мешает "если" принадлежать обеим частям гипотетического ССП. По смыслу не: *или ЕСЛИ кто-то томится*... Но вопрос о принадлежности хвостов полетит к автору пламенным приветом: это я прозевала!

Comment: Еще вариант:  пицца и паста, бычьи желудки и даже хвосты. (две пары)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova, Тогда, может, так: если ... или если ... — в любом случае ...

Comment: Нет, нельзя смысловой самодеятельности при живом мемуаристе! Его спрашивать надо... разрешение получать.

Answer (score 4):

Если наскучили пицца, паста, и бычьи желудки, и даже хвосты или вдруг кто-то томится по далёкой Индии, – в любом случае приятное разнообразие в рацион внесёт симпатичный ресторан домашней индийской кухни.

1). Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144
...перед главной частью, которой предшествует **ряд однородных придаточных**, если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения **на две части** (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза):
*Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам* (Кр.); *Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем* (Добр.);

2). Повтор союза ЕСЛИ необязателен.